# VBA form to show cell value

Tags: forms, vba

I have an Excel VBA form to enter data into a worksheet.
Last column of my worksheet CC contains a formula which calculates some input fields. It is a very long though simple formula.

Is it possible that while I am entering the data in the form, a field in the VBA form itself keeps showing me running result of the inputs made based on the formula in the worksheet column CC?
I don’t know how to write that long formula in VBA so want to find out if there is a way around it.

If not possible, how about while the data has been entered in the form, there is a button CHECK RESULT. Clicking this button temporarily enters the form data to spreadsheet, populating CC cell and that result shows up as message box while the VBA data form is still open.
This result message box could have two buttons, CONFIRM ENTRY or CANCEL.
If cancel is clicked then the data entered in the spreadsheet is deleted. If confirm is clicked, then entered data stays.

Kind of urgent if someone can suggest a solution.
I have added image of my VBA form.

Comment: I would think the easiest way would be to convert the formula into VBA and you should look down that path.  All Excel spreadsheet functions are available in VBA (eg `dResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A1:B2"))`) so you should be able to construct the formula.  If you post the formula it would help.

Answer (score 0):

In the most basic manner to answer your sub question:

"Is it possible that while I am entering the data in the form, a field in the VBA form itself keeps showing me running result of the inputs made based on the formula in the worksheet column CC?"

Yes it's possible.

- Asumming have a working formula anywhere in the sheet. Which you do according to your question.
- Assuming your Sheet doesn't have a code like `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` , to say your Sheet is in automatic calculation mode it will show you the running results.
- You use key press or enter events in the Form to update the Sheet column `CC`

Your approach with buttons and message box seems fine. Why don't you give it a try and let us know with any issues you face.

Some hints:

- `UserForm1.Show vbModeless` [property](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/exceldev/thread/13a79f7d-9622-45ab-9af1-f4dcaec53205)
- [Allow worksheet access while user form is open](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=150208)
- [Editing spreadsheet while user form is open](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/415566-editing-spreadsheet-while-userform-open.html)
- How to show messagebox from cell changed event while user form is open?